# I need to replace this <ServerURL>https://localhost:${my.port}${my.context}services/</ServerURL> using ansible

Tags: ansible

hi i need to replace below  string  in ansible

'https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/'

with 
'localhost:2222/services'

i have used a command for that using ansible. but it doesn't working.

```
 name: set ServerURL of the  AuthManager  [HUB_HOME]/repository/conf/api-manager.xml
 replace: 
    dest: "{{packFolderNameAM}}/repository/conf/api-manager.xml"
    regexp: '<ServerURL>https://localhost:${my.port}${my.context}services/</ServerURL>'- name: set ServerURL of the  AuthManager  [HUB_HOME]/repository/conf/api-manager.xml
    replace: 'localhost/9444/services'
    before: 'Admin username for the Authentication manager'
    backup: yes
```

please help me with this. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

As api-manager.xml is a file. We can keep in side templates: as different files with  and dynamically copy the file using tags: in tasks:

This will prevent the scripting.

Or

Keep the template with the mentioned variables and  define variables in playbooks var: 
or 
in role based var /main.yml file https://localhost:${my.port}${my.context}services/ 
Then variables will get populated

EXAMPLE:
 [image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate this answer because I haven’t use template:

Comment: Please refer the example added